# Covariance of geometric Brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, martingales, covariance

Consider the following exercise (ex. 3.2.5 from Calin's book *An Informal Introduction to stochastic Calculus with Applications*):

> If $X_t=e^{W_t}$, find $\mathrm{Cov}(X_s, X_t)$   a. by direct
>   computation;   b. by using the previous exercise.
>
> The previous exercise is:
>
> **Exercise 3.2.4.** Let $X_t = e^{W_t}$. $\\$
>
> $(a)$ Show that $X_t$ is not a martingale.
>
> $(b)$ Show that $e^{-\frac t2}X_t$ is a martingale.
>
> $(c)$ Show that for any constant $c\in\mathbb R$, the process $Y_t= e^{cW_t - \frac12 c^2t}$ is a martingale.

Supposing $s<t$, by direct computation I find:
$$
\begin{array}
\mathbb{E}[e^{W_t}e^{W_s}] &= \mathbb{E}[e^{W_t - W_s} e^{2W_s}] \\
 &= \mathbb{E}[e^{W_t - W_s}]\mathbb{E}[e^{2W_s}] \\
 &= e^{\frac12(t-s)} e^{2s} \\
 &= e^{\frac12 t + \frac32 s}.
\end{array}
$$
So the covariance would be:
$$
\begin{array}
\mathrm{Cov}(X_s, X_t) &= \mathbb{E}[X_s X_t] - \mathbb{E}[X_s]\mathbb{E}[X_t] \\
 &= e^{\frac12 (t + s)}(e^s - 1).
\end{array}
$$

Using the previous exercise, I would do:
$$
\begin{array}
\mathbb{E}[e^{-\frac12 t}e^{W_t}e^{-\frac12 s}e^{W_s}] &= e^{-\frac12(t+s)} \mathbb{E}[e^{W_t}e^{W_s}].
\end{array}
$$
Note that on the right hand side we have exactly what we need for computing the covariance.
Now, ideally I would like to split that left hand side into the product of the expectations of the terms in $t$ and of those in $s$, apply the martingale property and conclude.
However I do not see how this is justified ($e^{W_t}$ surely depends on $e^{W_s}$), and indeed even if I did, I would not recover the result obtained by explicit computation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that that $W_0 = 0$,

\begin{align}
E[e^{W_s}e^{W_t}] &= e^{\frac{t}{2}}E[e^{W_s}e^{W_t - \frac{t}{2}}] \\
&= e^{\frac{t}{2}}E[e^{W_s}E[e^{W_t - \frac{t}{2}}|\mathcal{F}_s]]
\quad \text{$W_s$ is $\mathcal{F}_s$-mesurable and thanks to b)}\\ 
&= e^{\frac{t}{2}}E[e^{2W_s - \frac{s}{2}}] \\
&= e^{\frac{t+3s}{2}}E[e^{2W_s - 2s}] \quad \text{thanks to c) with $\lambda=2$}\\
&= e^{\frac{t+3s}{2}}\\
\end{align}
Now :
\begin{align}
E[e^{W_s}]E[e^{W_t}] &= e^{\frac{t+s}{2}}E[e^{W_s- \frac{s}{2}}]E[e^{W_t - \frac{t}{2}}] \\
&= e^{\frac{t+s}{2}}\\
\end{align}
You have all the ingredients to compute the covariance.

Comment: Nice trick in the first equality. Thanks.