# Discrepancy of answers between differing computations of $E[e^{W_s}e^{W_t}]$ ($W_t$ being the Wiener process)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

I was looking at [another thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3531785/745726), and the following two distinct solutions to $E[e^{W_s}e^{W_t}]$ (assume that $W_0 = 0$ and $t>s$) were given, with both giving identical answers (I have slightly re-written the notation in the second solution for the reader's sake):

1.

> by direct computation I find:
> $$
> \begin{array}
> \mathbb{E}[e^{W_t}e^{W_s}] &= \mathbb{E}[e^{W_t - W_s} e^{2W_s}] \\
>  &= \mathbb{E}[e^{W_t - W_s}]\mathbb{E}[e^{2W_s}] \\
>  &= e^{\frac12(t-s)} e^{2s} \\
>  &= e^{\frac12 t + \frac32 s}.
> \end{array}
> $$

2. 

> Given the facts that for $X_t = e^{W_t}$,
>
> $(a)$ $e^{-\frac t2}X_t$ is a martingale and
>
> $(b)$ For any constant $\lambda \in\mathbb R$, the process $Y_t= e^{\lambda W_t - \frac12 \lambda^2t}$ is a martingale,
>
> we have
>
> \begin{align}
> E[e^{W_s}e^{W_t}] &= e^{\frac{t}{2}}E[e^{W_s}e^{W_t - \frac{t}{2}}] \\
> &= e^{\frac{t}{2}}E[e^{W_s}E[e^{W_t - \frac{t}{2}}|\mathcal{F}_s]]
> \quad \text{$W_s$ is $\mathcal{F}_s$-mesurable and thanks to a)}\\ 
> &= e^{\frac{t}{2}}E[e^{2W_s - \frac{s}{2}}] \\
> &= e^{\frac{t+3s}{2}}E[e^{2W_s - 2s}] \quad \text{thanks to b) with $\lambda=2$}\\
> &= e^{\frac{t+3s}{2}}\\
> \end{align}

On the other hand, I took quite a different approach, getting a different answer (note that I write $\exp(x)$ instead of $e^x$):

> Let $Z \sim N(0,1)$. Then its moment generating function is,
>
> \begin{align*}
> E[\exp{(\lambda Z)}] &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp\left({\lambda z})\exp({-z^2/2}\right)dz \\
> &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\left({(-z^2 + 2\lambda z)/{2}}\right)dz \\
> &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\left({{-(z + \lambda)^2}/{2} + {\lambda^2}/{2}}\right)dz \\
> &= \exp\left({\frac{\lambda^2}{2}}\right)\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\exp\left({{-(z + \lambda)^2}/2}\right)}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}dz .
> \end{align*}
>
> Since the function inside the last integral is precisely the pdf of $N(\lambda , 1)$, its integral equals 1. Therefore we have,
> $$E[\exp{(\lambda Z)}] = \exp\left({\frac{\lambda^2}{2}}\right).$$
>
> Now,
> \begin{align*}
> E[\exp\left({W_s}\right)\exp\left({W_t}\right)] &= E[\exp\left({W_s + W_t}\right)] \\
> &= E[\exp\left({(\sqrt{s} + \sqrt{t})Z}\right)] \text{ since $W_t \sim N(0,t)$}\\
> &= \exp\left({\frac{(\sqrt{s} + \sqrt{t})^2}{2}}\right) \\
> &= \exp\left( \frac{s + t + 2\sqrt{st}}{2} \right). \\
> \end{align*}

Since $t > s$, we can write $t = a s$ for some $a > 1$. Hence,
\begin{align*}
E[\exp\left({W_s}\right)\exp\left({W_t}\right)] &= \exp\left( \frac{s + t + 2\sqrt{s(as)}}{2} \right) = \exp\left( \frac{s + t + 2s\sqrt{a}}{2} \right) \\
&> \exp\left( \frac{s + t + 2s \cdot \sqrt{1}}{2} \right) = \exp\left( \frac{t + 3s}{2} \right),
\end{align*}

and hence the discrepancy is clear (with the two answers being equal only if $s = t$).

Naturally, my question is where my mistake is. Thanks!

Comment: Your assumtion is wrong. Note that $W_{t+s} \sim N(0, t+s)$ but it'is completly diffrent than $W_s + W_t$. In the first case you take distribution of Wiener proces at time $t+s$ in the second case you add two correlated process ($W_t$ is equal $W_s$ up to time $s$). Hence You have to find joint distribution of $(W_t,W_s)$

Comment: I have used the fact that $W_t \sim N(0,t)$, which implies that $W_t = \sqrt{t} Z$ where $Z \sim N(0,1)$.

More generally, we have that for any random variable $X$ distributed by $N(\mu , \sigma^2)$, $X = \mu + \sigma Z$. This is also stated on the [normal distribution's Wikipedia page in the 'General normal distribution' section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#General_normal_distribution).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue with your second computation is that $W_s + W_t$ does not agree in distribution with $(\sqrt{s} + \sqrt{t}) Z$ for a standard Gaussian $Z$. We can see this by a computation. First:
$$(\sqrt{s} + \sqrt{t}) Z \sim N(0, s + t + 2\sqrt{st})$$
Now observing that $(W_s, W_t)$ is a bivariate normal vector, we have that $W_s + W_t$ is normally distributed with:
$$\begin{align*}
E(W_s + W_t) &= 0 \\
\mathrm{Var}(W_s + W_t) &= \mathrm{Var}(W_s) + \mathrm{Var}(W_t) + 2 \mathrm{Cov}(W_s, W_t) = s + t + 2 s \land t
\end{align*}$$
In particular the variances (hence, the distributions) of these two random variables do not agree, and thus:
$$E(\exp (W_s + W_t)) \neq E( \exp ((\sqrt{s} + \sqrt{t}) Z))$$

Answer (score 1):

I'm rusty on this, so please wait for confirmation, but I think your mistake is in
$$
E[\exp(W_s + W_t)] \overset{!}{=} E[\exp((\sqrt{s} + \sqrt{t})Z)]
$$
Even if we take $s = 0$, say, then it is not the case that
$$
E[\exp(W_t)] \overset{!}{=} E[\exp(\sqrt{t}Z)]
$$
This is an issue with expectations, not anything specific to do with Brownian motion.

**Edit:** this is incorrect, I misread the equation as something about expectations commuting with functions of random variables.

Comment: I am not an expert either, but in my lecture notes the bottom equality is stated: https://i.imgur.com/FIScA9w.png

Comment: @VentsiRadev yes, thank you -- see edit.